# How to write a .txt file to a list

Tags: python, file

Very reversed question here, I need to take a .txt file and add it to a list.

The output file:

```
abc123
```

What the list should be:

```
list = ["abc123"]
```

Comment: Create an empty list.  Open the file, read each line, and append it to the list.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: The difficulty is I'm not that smart.

Comment: It's not about being smart. There's already a ton of tutorials and existing posts on how to read files and work with lists. As noted in [ask], doing your research should be your first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
with open("","r") as f:
    data=f.readlines()
#Or same:
f=open("","r")
data=f.readlines()
f.close()
```

`data` is in list, it read each line. And put each line in list.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean add the content to a list?
If so, you may use:

```py
with open("filename") as f:
    content = f.read()
yourlist.append(content)
# Do something here...
```

If you want to add the file object to a list, you may use:

```py
with open("filename") as f:
    yourlist.append(f)
    # Do something here...
```